# Magento 2 nginx ssl problems

Tags: magento2, nginx, ssl, https

I have Magento 2 installed on ubuntu 16.04 with nginx webserver. The site is working pretty good, then i try to enable whole site SSL from letsencrypt and I run into problems.

my root dir is /var/www/html with the magento install directly in there

I change the settings in magento so the secure url is https://example.com/ and I set nginx up as per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04.

In sites-enabled i have

> ```
> upstream fastcgi_backend {
>         server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock; }  server {
>
>         listen 80;
>         server_name www.sxcmarket.com;
>         set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
>         set $MAGE_MODE developer;
>         include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;  }
> ```

When I do nginx -t it shows no problems. Then when i try to go to either www.example.com or example.com i get 403 error

when i check the nginx/error.log I get the following

> 2016/10/10 06:12:23 [error] 8335#8335: *11 directory index of
>   "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: _,
>   request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "example.com"

Ive tried a number of different SSL setups and get the same result each time

Comment: could you check magento root folder user, group and their read write permission?

Comment: ls -l of html
folders - drwxr-x--- 12 myuser www-data     4096 Oct  9 21:05 html

root@magento:/var/www# groups myuser
myuser: www-data sudo